# Find the union, intersection, and etc of 3 sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A={x\in\Bbb N|\exists n\in\Bbb N, x=3n}$

$B={x\in\Bbb N|\exists n\in\Bbb N, x=3n+1}$

$C={x\in\Bbb N|\exists n\in\Bbb N, x=3n+2}$

What is

a) $A\cup B$

b) $A\cap B$

c)$A\cup B \cup C$

d) $\Bbb N\setminus(B \cup C)$.

This is what I have done so far.

To find a) $A \cup B$= {3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13,15,16,...} (I noticed the pattern, but don't know how to write the rule)

b)$A\cap B$=$\emptyset$

c)$A\cup B\cup C$=${x\ge3}$

d)$\Bbb N\setminus(B \cup C)$=1 $\lt $x $\le$4.

Am I on the right track? If I did anything wrong, please correct me. Thank you.

Comment: D) is incorrect.  For the "partern" of A simply describe it.  All natural  numbers ge 3 that can't be written as 3k+2.  Are you sure your text defines the natural numbers to not include 0?

Comment: Assuming $\mathbb{N}$ does not contain $0$, yes, except for letter $(d)$.

Answer (score 0):

a) Something like this:

$A \cup B = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \text{ } \big| \text{ } x \geq 3 \land \big[x  \equiv 1 (\bmod 3) \lor x \equiv 0 (\bmod 3)\big]\} = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \text{ } | \text{ } x \geq 3 \land \big[3 | (n-1) \lor 3|n\big]\}$

d) $\mathbb{N} \setminus (B \cup C) = (\mathbb{N} \setminus B) \cap (\mathbb{N} \setminus C) = A \cup \{1, 2\}$

Comment: how did you get d?

Comment: $A = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} | x \geq 3 \land \lor x \equiv 0 \bmod 3\} = \{x \in \mathbb{N} | x \geq 3 \text{ & } x \not\equiv 1 \bmod 3 \text{ & } x \not\equiv 2 \bmod 3\} = $ $(\mathbb{N} \setminus B) \cup (\mathbb{N} \setminus C) \setminus \{1, 2\}.$

This would indeed, as noted by Bram28, be easier by taking whole numbers rather than strictly natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $0 \not \in \Bbb N$:

a) $A \cup B = \{ x \in \Bbb N | \exists n \: ( x = 3n \lor x = 3n + 1 \}$

b) $A \cap B = \emptyset$

c) $A \cup B \cup C = \Bbb N \setminus \{1,2\} = \{ x \in \Bbb N | x \ge 3\}$

d) $\Bbb N \setminus B \cup C = A \cup \{1,2\}$

Assuming $0 \in \Bbb N$:

a) $A \cup B = \Bbb N \setminus C$

b) $A \cap B = \emptyset$

c) $A \cup B \cup C = \Bbb N$

d) $\Bbb N \setminus B \cup C = A$

Comment: 0 is not in the naturals.

Comment: @Lily Some say it is, some say it isn't. Did your teacher say it isn't? It sure is a lot easier for these questions to assume it is!

Comment: Yes, I asked my professor and he said 0 is not included in the naturals in this case.

Comment: @Lily OK, then your original c) was just fine. I added the answers for $0 \not \in \Bbb N$, but kept the answers $0 \in \Bbb N$ just to show how much nicer the answers would be :)